# Only cropping/appending a subset of images from an image sequence

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have a numbered image sequence that I need to crop and append, but only certain frame ranges.

Example, sequence of 100 images named as follows:

```
frame001.jpg
frame002.jpg
frame003.jpg
...
```

Sometimes might only need to crop and append images 20-30, or other time, 5-75.

How can I specify a range? Simply outputting to a PNG.

Comment: Please provide specific example of filenames, your desired result using the example filenames and what you have tried (including research) so far.

Comment: Filenames added @tshiono. I haven't tried much, I have little experience with Imagemagick and bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For examle, if you want to pick the jpg files in the range of `20-30`
and generate a png file appending them, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a input                                        # an array to store jpg filenames
for i in $(seq 20 30); do                               # loop between 20 and 30
    input+=( "$(printf "frame%03d.jpg" "$i")" )         # append the filename one by one to the array
done
echo convert -append "${input[@]}" "output.png"         # generate a png file appending the files
```

If the output command looks good, drop `echo`.

If you are unsure how to run a bash script and prefer a one-liner, please try instead:

```
declare -a input; for i in $(seq 20 30); do input+=( "$(printf "frame%03d.jpg" "$i")" ); done; echo convert -append "${input[@]}" "output.png"
```

**[Edit]**
If you want to `crop` the images with e.g. `720x480+300+200`,
then please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a input
for i in $(seq 20 30); do
    input+=( "$(printf "frame%03d.jpg" "$i")" )
done
convert "${input[@]}" -crop 720x480+300+200 -append "output.png"
```

The order of options and filenames doesn't matter here, but I have followed
the modern style of `ImageMagick` usage to place the input filenames first.

Comment: This works very well! Thank you! My only other question: how can I crop each image, before appending, without cropping the original file?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I've added the code to `crop` the image in `[Edit]` section in my answer. BR.

Comment: Works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. I'm very unfamiliar with ImageMagick and bash, and you've literally saved me days of work.